# Redux/Thunk - async fetch function issues

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

So i've been practicing on a project of mine where i have a `async getItems` function in react component named `Sheet`. It works just fine since i logged the result in console. However when i try to apply redux/thunk way to fetch items from the same API, my new function doesnt even trigger. Tried console.logging the first line of it and nothing happens. Here is hwo they look.

**Simple and working one:**

```
const getItems = async (date) =>{
    let request = {}
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`${apiURL}/${date}`, request);
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setItems(data);

    } catch (error){
        console.log("Error fetching data")
    }  
}
```

**The one that im trying to implement instead of the old one, this one doesnt work/trigger:**

```
const fetchItems = () => async dispatch =>{
    console.log("Entered fetch items func");
    let request = {};
    let response = await timesheetApi.get(`/17-3-2021`);
    // TRIED USING FETCH INSTEAD AS WELL, NO RESULT AS WELL:
    // let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:44377/${date}`, request);
    // let data = await response.json();
    console.log(response); 
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS', payload: response })
}
```

Both first one and the one that isnt working im trying to call in `useEffect` of `Sheet` component.
*First triggers and gets the array of results*, but when i *comment it out and put the second one in the same place - it doesnt even trigger* (cant debug).

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong by this code?

**P.S setup from index.js**

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

**Axios setup in api folder > timesheetApi.js** (But i tried using fetch as well, same (no) result"

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:44377',
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
function reducer (state = initialStore, action)  {

    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.TRIGGER_MODAL:
                console.log("Triggered loading");
                return { ...state, showModal: !state.showModal }

        case actionTypes.FETCH_ITEMS:
            console.log("Reducer - FETCH_ITEMS case");
            return state;
```

Note that im testing/having both functions in `Sheet` component and `useEffect` to simplify testing. Also date is hardcoded in the second one out of the same reason.

Comment: how are you calling them in useEffect? That is the single most important thing

Comment: @phry well i just say `getItems("17-03-2021")` , for the other one i do `fetchItems()` since i hardcoded the date inside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `fetchItems` as a thunk action creator, but inside your `useEffect` you are just calling it without actually dispatching it.

That is akin to defining an action, but never sending it off to redux.

In your `useEffect`, you have to `dispatch(fetchItems())`

Comment: Correct! I forgot to add my answer, i figured this out 5minutes ago! However i have a new problem. My `console.log` triggers in `fetchItems` and the data is okay. Then it triggers in reducer but the data there is undefined when i log it before setting to state. In reducer i am saying `return {...state, items: payload.items }`. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok i just figured it out, in my `fetchItems` i need to say `payload: {items}` instead of `payload: items`. AKA send an object